# SQL-Server with Visual c++ , connection fail ( SQL_ERROR)

Tags: c++, sql-server, visual-c++, database-connection

Hi i'm just doing a connection with c++ to SqlServer , i'm using de IDE VS 2017 ,SQL Server 2017 
On runtime I get a error of SqlServer (its like a mem dir or something like that because it change between executions)
These are my vars:

```
SQLHANDLE SQLEnvHandle = NULL;
SQLHANDLE SQLConnectionHandle = NULL;
SQLHANDLE SQLStatementHandle = NULL;
SQLRETURN retCode = 0;

char SQLQuery[] = "SELECT * FROM employee";
```

And this is my connection :

```
retCode = SQLDriverConnect(SQLConnectionHandle, NULL, (SQLWCHAR*)"DRIVER=SQL Server; SERVER=myServer, 1433; DATABASE=testing; UID=user; PWD=password; Trusted_Connection=True;", SQL_NTS, retConString, 1024, NULL, SQL_DRIVER_NOPROMPT);
```

I tried to modify the conection in the field DRIVER with this : DRIVER={SQL Server} 
and adding the Trusted_Connection=[True|yes]

I have the driver of Sql Server listed on ODBC Driver list

Following to the connection I have a switch case and I already identify in which case it enters the condition of error , its the following:

```
case SQL_ERROR:
            showSQLError(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, SQLConnectionHandle);
            retCode = -1;
            break;
```

And I do not know what to do to solve this error:/

This is a c++ console app not a windows form using .net .